# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola amigos me pueden ayudar con un error en tiempo de ejecucion,porfavor si alguien me da una idea para resolverlo.

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**

llevo mucho tiempo tratandop de solucionar probando algunas soluciones en google pero sigue lo mismo.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {  
        Socket misocket= new Socket("127.0.0.1",999);


       paqueteuno datos = new paqueteuno();
       datos.setNick(Nick.getText());
       datos.setIp(Ip.getText());
       datos.setMensaje(Mensaje.getText());

        ObjectOutputStream paquete_datos = new ObjectOutputStream(misocket.getOutputStream());
         paquete_datos.writeObject(datos);
        misocket.close();
        /*
        DataOutputStream salida = new DataOutputStream(a.getOutputStream());
        salida.writeUTF(Mensaje.getText());
        salida.close();
        */




    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }


}
```

---

```
package cliente;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class paqueteuno implements Serializable
{
 private String Nick;

 private String Ip;

 private String Mensaje;


        public String getNick() {
            return Nick;
        }

        public void setNick(String Nick) {
            this.Nick = Nick;
        }

        public String getIp() {
            return Ip;
        }

        public void setIp(String Ip) {
            this.Ip = Ip;
        }

        public String getMensaje() {
            return Mensaje;
        }

        public void setMensaje(String Mensaje) {
            this.Mensaje = Mensaje;
        }   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la traza del error, ya que en ella debe decir cual es la clase que no se encontró.

Comment: A que te refieres con la traza del error ?

Comment: La salida que sale en la consola del NetBeans cuando se produce el error

Comment: Y el error se lanza en el cliente o en el servidor que escucha en el puerto 999?

Comment: Ese error ocurre cuando intentas usar una `Clase` que no existe en el programa, por lo general ocurre cuando falta instalar alguna librería o la misma no se ha instalado completa. En el largo mensaje de error que muestra Java te dirá qué clase es, generalmente aparece cerca de donde dice `Caused by...`

Comment: Para ser mas especifico el erro esta en esta linea de codigo :    paquete_datos.writeObject(datos);   y es del cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expeción que indicas `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` no es lanzada en ningún método de la clase `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` al momento de la serialización del objeto escrito en `paquete_datos.writeObject(...);`, del `stream`. Sin embargo **SI** es lanzanda al momento de deserialización en la clase `java.io.ObjectInputStream`, lo puedes ver acá:

[Documentación del método readObject() de la clase ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject())

Y este error ocurre cuando la clase que intentas enviar (en este caso intentas enviar una clase llamada `paqueteuno`) no se encuentra en el extremo del flujo de datos (`stream`), y esto se debe a que al momento de realizar un `readObject()` la clase enviada se deserializa y si esta no se encuentra lanzará el error.

Por esto es necesario tener una clase con el mismo nombre, las mismas variables y con el mismo `serialVersionUID` en ambos paquetes (supongo que así como tienes un `Cliente` también tienes un `Servidor`, así que la clase `paqueteuno` **debe** estar en ambos paquetes).

La deserialización por defecto trata de reconstruir la clase enviada, creando una nueva instancia de esa clase `paqueteuno`, por lo que si esta clase no se encuentra, aparecerá el error.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion :

La clase paqueteuno que me decia que no se encontraba(error),esa clase la converti a un jar y luego la agregue a mi proyecto cliente y servidor,con eso se soluciono.

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Por qué lo convertiste a un .jar?, tal vez hubiera sido más simple (que tener que convertir a .jar e implementarlo en tu proyecto), copiar la clase `paqueteuno` y pegarla en el lado del servidor también

Comment: En estos momentos no lo he probado bien, pero me parece que en el lado del servidor, tendrías que tener una paquete llamado `cliente` y ahí pegas la clase `paqueteuno`, de esa manera al momento de deserializar, la clase se buscará en el paquete `cliente` de la clase `Servidor`.

Comment: C. Rodriguez tambien funciono la ultima parte que comentastes,le puse el mismo nombre del paquete y funciono.Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, ;-). Por cierto, te recomiendo no hacer una nueva respuesta, si lo que quieres es agregar algo más de información (como esta respuesta que pusiste), edita tu pregunta y agregalo al final. Saludos

Comment: Lo del jar en realidad sería una decisión de diseño. Por otro lado el nombrado de la clase paqueteuno va contra estándares. El nombre correcto sería: PaqueteUno.